# I wanted to import pandas and numpy on jupyter notebook and received [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, jupyter-notebook

Warning: I'm a beginner and will have trouble understanding a complicated answer. However, I have used Jupyter Notebook months ago and did not have any problems with using these same packages when I first started learning. Is it possible that when I installed PyCharm afterwards that it messed up my Jupyter Notebook set up?

Code I wrote:

```
    import numpy as np
    import pandas as pd

    from pandas import Series, DataFrame
```

Error I received:

```
    OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
    <ipython-input-1-1de8dee942b6> in <module>
    ----> 1 import numpy as np
          2 import pandas as pd
          3 
          4 from pandas import Series, DataFrame

    ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\__init__.py in <module>
        136 
        137     # Allow distributors to run custom init code
    --> 138     from . import _distributor_init
        139 
        140     from . import core

    ~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\numpy\_distributor_init.py in <module>
         24                 # NOTE: would it change behavior to load ALL
         25                 # DLLs at this path vs. the name restriction?
    ---> 26                 WinDLL(os.path.abspath(filename))
         27                 DLL_filenames.append(filename)
         28         if len(DLL_filenames) > 1:

    ~\Documents\Anaconda\lib\ctypes\__init__.py in __init__(self, name, mode, handle, use_errno, 
    use_last_error, winmode)
        371 
        372         if handle is None:
    --> 373             self._handle = _dlopen(self._name, mode)
        374         else:
        375             self._handle = handle

    OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on some extra steps? How did you install numpy and how are you running your program?

Comment: @khuynh I'm using the Anaconda prompt to load up Jupyter Notebook. Honestly, I watched a video and blindly set up Anaconda, Jupyter notebook, and Python3, but I'm confused because I didn't have any problems using Numpy in November when I tried it out, so I don't know why I do now. Also, I have a small program also made in November that gave me an error when I refreshed it because it is not recognizing the package matplotlib.pyplot when it worked fine before too. Are these problems connected?

Comment: it looks like you may have a couple different versions of python installed on your machine. If you look closely at the traceback, you can see you're running code from `~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38` and `~\Documents\Anaconda`. I would check your [`PATH`](https://geek-university.com/python/add-python-to-the-windows-path/) and uninstall/remove the non-anaconda version from your system PATH @AlexRZ99